# Looking for title of SciFi story (on TV) about invisible men who fix things out of place in time

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, tv, time

I remember a short I saw on TV many years ago about time as a continuum, I think a train?  there were men who fixed things that were out of place.  It was an explanation of why you would think your glasses were on the table.  They would not be there but when you went back, they were there.  The invisible workers were supposed to always be ready to have everything in place.  A woman was planning to dust a high bookcase, so they sprinkled dust on it right before she dusted.  I think she ends up accidentally seeing one of the time fixers.  I always think of this story when I am missing something and then it shows up. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"[A Matter of Minutes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Matter_of_Minutes)" is the third segment of the fifteenth episode from the first season (1985–86) of the television series The Twilight Zone. This segment is based on Theodore Sturgeon's short story "Yesterday Was Monday", first published in June 1941. It follows a couple who accidentally discover that every minute of time actually takes place in a different location, each carefully crafted to maintain the illusion of continuity.

Comment: Not sure, but I think there was another similar story the OP might be remembering, where they were not "constructing" time, where there were not so many "workers" building everything instead, just a few who were tweaking the area, (i.e. putting dust on high shelves, before the protagonist cleans it, or putting missing glasses back where they were supposed to be.) But I only have vague recollections of it. [Would probably be an episode on a Twilight Zone, or Outer Limits, or similar TV show)

Comment: If the OP remember the "fix-it guys" being faceless blue guys this is it for sure.

Comment: YES!!!  I remember the blue guys fixing everything just as it is about to happen.  I think of it all the time.  Thank you so much!  For some reason I had a “time train” in my mind, but I am sure this is it!! Now that I know it I just found it on YouTube.  TIme is “box-cars” (my train reference).